# Can't scale frequencies, always jumps to lowest

Tags: cpu, cpufreq

The title pretty much explains it. I know this is not a hardware issue. CPU is an Intel Core Duo

Output of `cpufreq-info`:

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.40 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.40 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.40 GHz:-nan%, 2.40 GHz:-nan%, 1.60 GHz:-nan%, 800 MHz:-nan%  (1)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.40 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.40 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave,     performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 800 MHz.
  cpufreq stats: 2.40 GHz:-nan%, 2.40 GHz:-nan%, 1.60 GHz:-nan%, 800 MHz:-nan%  (1)
```

I need my CPU back to be able to hit it's 2.4 GHz mark. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Dell uses a chip that regulates CPU power.

If one is using an unauthorized charger, Dell PCs will block CPU power. This is a poor way to force you to buy only OEM chargers.

To fix it, one must edit the `/etc/default/grub` file. On the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, add `processor.ignore_ppc=1` after `splash` but before the closing `"`.

(Ex: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.ignore_ppc=1"`)

[(Src)](http://www.woolie.co.uk/article/dell-laptop-stuck-800mhz-linux-fix/)